# Rebuild domain model from persistance storage

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am a newby to the concept of DDD, and running to some issues when rebuilding my domain model from the persistance layer, namely how to handle object creation wich would normally not be allowed due to businessrules.

For example, the concept of an Invoice and InvoiceRows. Bussinessrules do not allow an invoicerow to be added to an invoice once the invoice has been sent to the customer.

My domain model will look something like this:

```
class Invoice
{
    List<InvoiceRow> _rows = new List<InvoiceRow>();

    public bool IsSent { get; private set; }

    Invoice(bool isSent)
    {
        this.IsSent = isSent;
    }

    public InvoiceRow AddRow(Product product, decimal amount)
    {
        if (IsSent) throw new InvalidOperationException("Invoice already sent to customer.");

        var row = new InvoiceRow(this, product, amount);

        _rows.Add(row);

        return row;
    }

    public void Send(object service)
    {
        if (IsSent) throw new InvoiceAlreadySentException();

        service.SendInvoice(this);

        this.IsSent = true;
    }
}

class InvoiceRow
{
    public Product Product { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; private set; }

    InvoiceRow(Invoice parent, Product product, decimal amount)
    {
        this.Invoice = parent;
        this.Product = product;
        this.Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

When rebuilding an Invoice model including its rows from the database, which has already been sent, the issue arises that adding invoice rows is rejected by the domain model, if the invoice has already been sent.

For example:

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice(invoiceDto.IsSent);

foreach(row in invoiceRowsDto)
{
    invoice.AddRow(row.Product, row.Amount); // Not allowed because the invocie has been sent...
}
```

Offcourse it is possible to add a constructor parameter with a list of rows, but this makes it possible to add the same list of rows to a different invoice.

```
var listOfRows = somelistofinvoicerowsretrievedfromdatabase;
var invoice1 = new Invoice(issent=true, listofrows);
var invoice2 = new Invoice(issent=false, listofrows);
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Depending on how far along you are with your project, [event sourcing](http://cqrsguide.com/doc:event-sourcing) might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it seems like your last idea is the right way to go. I like to have at least three constructors: a 'new entity' constructor, a 'copy entity' constructor, and a 'reconstitute from persistence' constructor. Sure, you *could* add the same list of rows to a different invoice, but when and where is that going to happen? Remember, domain-driven design is helpful for structuring business rules within a code base, but at some point you have to accept the fact that "what if a developer typed this line of code that would be bad" is always a possibility no matter how well you model your business rules into code.

EDIT:

Just wanted to add, if you expose your domain model through a **Service Layer**, your domain model could be internal to that project's assembly, and clients would only need to interface with the Service Layer using either externally visible **Data Transfer Objects** or primitive types -- this way, consuming clients would not be able to cause an invalid operation and your business logic is still neatly organized according to the problem domain,